# run multiple webservices at a time

Tags: java

I have written a webservice which is taking URL as an input and producing a JSON respone. My problem is that now I have list of 1000 URLs and want to execute maximum threads of Webapplications to get output. Like I want to execute 100 instances of webservice at a time to get response.Please can anybody give some guidance how can I do it using java.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

Are you saying you want to stress test your web service?

If so, look at [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) or [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do 1000 *concurrent* requests, instead of doing them one-by-one.

If you can write Java code to do *one* request, you can write a program which spawns 1000 threads each doing one request.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)